# Tensorflow Lite fails with error code (Compulab Yocto Image)

Tags: tensorflow, yocto, bitbake

Currently I am building an image for the IMX8M-Plus Board with a Yocto-Project on Windows using WSL2.

I enlarged the standard size of the WSL2 image from 250G to 400G, as this project gets to around 270G.

The initialization process is identical with the one proposed from compulab -> [Github-Link](https://github.com/compulab-yokneam/meta-bsp-imx8mp/tree/hardknott-5.10.72-2.2.0)

During the building process the `do_configure` step of tensorflow lite fails.

The log of the bitbake process that fails is as following:

```
bitbake -k imx-image-full    
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.50.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "ubuntu-20.04"
TARGET_SYS           = "aarch64-poky-linux"
MACHINE              = "ucm-imx8m-plus"
DISTRO               = "fsl-imx-xwayland"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "5.10-hardknott"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "aarch64 armv8a crc cortexa53 crypto"
TARGET_FPU           = ""
meta                 
meta-poky            = "HEAD:269265c00091fa65f93de6cad32bf24f1e7f72a3"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-python          = "HEAD:f44e1a2b575826e88b8cb2725e54a7c5d29cf94a"
meta-freescale       = "HEAD:469d6c958c76ea235b3d3c1527e797ce3a7392e3"
meta-freescale-3rdparty = "HEAD:f8150f3b37cb83cba1f9e2378e57bb63e02d4610"
meta-freescale-distro = "HEAD:e6daa26ba1f748326546063d63a085ae671827d9"
meta-bsp             
meta-sdk             
meta-ml              
meta-v2x             = "HEAD:30eff0d5a090d34690f0261b2899d5a5cd94c5ab"
meta-nxp-demo-experience = "HEAD:9dcc11ea9f525cffedbb28895e0abb443e56c3e0"
meta-chromium        = "HEAD:8be1d3a0ba0cf32e61144900597207af5698c10d"
meta-clang           = "HEAD:b0d805060791006d651efd3d7ae3dd5add8f70fe"
meta-gnome           
meta-networking      
meta-filesystems     = "HEAD:f44e1a2b575826e88b8cb2725e54a7c5d29cf94a"
meta-qt5             = "HEAD:43f8f539d40070a70fe89136db89bf5bb1dfe7ed"
meta-python2         = "HEAD:8db9e4f6ceae33d7a4f55453d31e69f9858af4eb"
meta-virtualization  = "HEAD:7f719ef40896b6c78893add8485fda995b00d51d"
meta-bsp-imx8mp      = "HEAD:f86605e9d86132c1c241e43741b1f301faeabee3"
meta-compulab        = "HEAD:ba7e04ae1149e5072efbc596bb385d8b4e61d261"
meta-desktop         
meta-multimedia      
meta-graphics        
meta-bsp             
meta-devtool         = "HEAD:ac7d62947423dcc08f5f146a325bea91369bc14d"

ERROR: tensorflow-lite-2.6.0-r0 do_configure: Execution of '/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.26681' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.26681
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/zlib/zlib_1.2.11.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3-pip_20.0.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python3-wheel_0.36.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/ninja/ninja_1.10.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.33.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/cmake/cmake-native_3.19.5.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/patch/patch_2.7.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.9.5.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python-numpy/python3-numpy_1.20.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python3_3.9.5.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/unzip/unzip_6.0.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python3-pybind11_2.6.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-graphics/jpeg/libjpeg-turbo_2.0.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/meta-imx/meta-ml/recipes-devtools/tensorflow-protobuf/tensorflow-protobuf_3.9.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_10.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.66.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_10.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['zlib', 'python3-pip-native', 'python3-wheel-native', 'ninja-native', 'pseudo-native', 'glibc', 'cmake-native', 'patch-native', 'python3', 'python3-numpy-native', 'python3-native', 'unzip-native', 'python3-pybind11-native', 'libjpeg-turbo', 'tensorflow-protobuf', 'gcc-cross-aarch64', 'quilt-native', 'gcc-runtime', 'python3-setuptools-native', 'linux-libc-headers', 'libgcc', 're2c-native', 'curl-native', 'bzip2-native', 'xz-native', 'zlib-native', 'ncurses-native', 'autoconf-native', 'libtool-native', 'attr-native', 'automake-native', 'libffi', 'gdbm', 'openssl', 'readline', 'bzip2', 'libnsl2', 'opkg-utils', 'libtirpc', 'libxcrypt', 'xz', 'util-linux', 'sqlite3', 'python3-cython-native', 'gdbm-native', 'libffi-native', 'libnsl2-native', 'util-linux-native', 'sqlite3-native', 'openssl-native', 'readline-native', 'pkgconfig-native', 'libtirpc-native', 'boost-native', 'mpfr-native', 'binutils-cross-aarch64', 'flex-native', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'libmpc-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'gmp-native', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'm4-native', 'cryptodev-linux', 'ncurses', 'bash-completion', 'libpam', 'util-linux-libuuid', 'libcap-ng', 'libpcre2-native', 'libcap-ng-native', 'util-linux-libuuid-native', 'icu-native', 'boost-build-native', 'cracklib', 'flex']
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| -- Setting build type to Release, for debug builds use'-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug'.
| -- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
| -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
| -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
| -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
| -- Check for working C compiler: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-gcc - skipped
| -- Detecting C compile features
| -- Detecting C compile features - done
| -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
| -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
| -- Check for working CXX compiler: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-g++ - skipped
| -- Detecting CXX compile features
| -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
| -- Looking for pthread.h
| -- Looking for pthread.h - found
| -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
| -- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
| -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
| -- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
| -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
| -- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
| -- Found Threads: TRUE
| -- Performing Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CPP11
| -- Performing Test EIGEN_COMPILER_SUPPORT_CPP11 - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_std=cpp03
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_std=cpp03 - Success
| -- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically
| -- Performing Test standard_math_library_linked_to_automatically - Success
| -- Standard libraries to link to explicitly: none
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_WERROR
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_WERROR - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_pedantic
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_pedantic - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wall
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wall - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wextra
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wextra - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wundef
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wundef - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcastalign
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcastalign - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcharsubscripts
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcharsubscripts - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnonvirtualdtor
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnonvirtualdtor - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wunusedlocaltypedefs
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wunusedlocaltypedefs - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wpointerarith
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wpointerarith - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wwritestrings
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wwritestrings - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wformatsecurity
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wformatsecurity - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wshorten64to32
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wshorten64to32 - Failed
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wlogicalop
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wlogicalop - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wenumconversion
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wenumconversion - Failed
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcpp11extensions
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wcpp11extensions - Failed
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wdoublepromotion
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wdoublepromotion - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wshadow
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wshadow - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnopsabi
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnopsabi - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnovariadicmacros
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnovariadicmacros - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnolonglong
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Wnolonglong - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnochecknew
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnochecknew - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnocommon
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fnocommon - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fstrictaliasing
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_fstrictaliasing - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd981
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd981 - Failed
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd2304
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_wd2304 - Failed
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_STRICTANSI
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_STRICTANSI - Failed
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Qunusedarguments
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_Qunusedarguments - Failed
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_ansi
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_ansi - Success
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_OPENMP
| -- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORT_OPENMP - Success
| -- Looking for a Fortran compiler
| -- Looking for a Fortran compiler - NOTFOUND
| --
| -- Configured Eigen 3.3.90
| --
| -- Available targets (use: cmake --build . --target TARGET):
| -- ---------+--------------------------------------------------------------
| -- Target   |   Description
| -- ---------+--------------------------------------------------------------
| -- install  | Install Eigen. Headers will be installed to:
| --          |     <CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX>/<INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR>
| --          |   Using the following values:
| --          |     CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX: /usr
| --          |     INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR:  include/eigen3
| --          |   Change the install location of Eigen headers using:
| --          |     cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=yourprefix
| --          |   Or:
| --          |     cmake . -DINCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR=yourdir
| -- doc      | Generate the API documentation, requires Doxygen & LaTeX
| -- blas     | Build BLAS library (not the same thing as Eigen)
| -- uninstall| Remove files installed by the install target
| -- ---------+--------------------------------------------------------------
| --
| -- Performing Test FARMHASH_HAS_BUILTIN_EXPECT
| -- Performing Test FARMHASH_HAS_BUILTIN_EXPECT - Success
| -- Looking for strtof_l
| -- Looking for strtof_l - found
| -- Looking for strtoull_l
| -- Looking for strtoull_l - found
| -- Using toolchain file: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/toolchain.cmake.
| -- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
| -- Found assembler: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-gcc
| -- Downloading clog to /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/clog-source (define CLOG_SOURCE_DIR to avoid it)
| -- Configuring done
| -- Generating done
| -- Build files have been written to: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/clog-download
| [1/9] Creating directories for 'clog'
| [2/9] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'clog'
| -- Downloading...
|    dst='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/clog-download/clog-prefix/src/d5e37adf1406cf899d7d9ec1d317c47506ccb970.tar.gz'
|    timeout='none'
|    inactivity timeout='none'
| -- Using src='https://github.com/pytorch/cpuinfo/archive/d5e37adf1406cf899d7d9ec1d317c47506ccb970.tar.gz'
| -- Downloading cpuinfo to /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/cpuinfo-source (define CPUINFO_SOURCE_DIR to avoid it)
| -- Configuring done
| -- Generating done
| -- Build files have been written to: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/cpuinfo-download
| [1/9] Creating directories for 'cpuinfo'
| [2/9] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'cpuinfo'
| -- Downloading...
|    dst='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/cpuinfo-download/cpuinfo-prefix/src/5916273f79a21551890fd3d56fc5375a78d1598d.zip'
|    timeout='none'
|    inactivity timeout='none'
| -- Using src='https://github.com/pytorch/cpuinfo/archive/5916273f79a21551890fd3d56fc5375a78d1598d.zip'
| -- [download 100% complete]
| -- verifying file...
|        file='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/cpuinfo-download/cpuinfo-prefix/src/5916273f79a21551890fd3d56fc5375a78d1598d.zip'
| -- Downloading... done
| -- extracting...
|      src='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/cpuinfo-download/cpuinfo-prefix/src/5916273f79a21551890fd3d56fc5375a78d1598d.zip'
|      dst='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/cpuinfo-source'
| -- extracting... [tar xfz]
| -- extracting... [analysis]
| -- extracting... [rename]
| -- extracting... [clean up]
| -- extracting... done
| [3/9] No update step for 'cpuinfo'
| [4/9] No patch step for 'cpuinfo'
| [5/9] No configure step for 'cpuinfo'
| [6/9] No build step for 'cpuinfo'
| [7/9] No install step for 'cpuinfo'
| [8/9] No test step for 'cpuinfo'
| [9/9] Completed 'cpuinfo'
| -- Downloading FP16 to /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/FP16-source (define FP16_SOURCE_DIR to avoid it)
| -- Configuring done
| -- Generating done
| -- Build files have been written to: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/FP16-download
| [1/9] Creating directories for 'fp16'
| [2/9] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'fp16'
| -- Downloading...
|    dst='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/FP16-download/fp16-prefix/src/0a92994d729ff76a58f692d3028ca1b64b145d91.zip'
|    timeout='none'
|    inactivity timeout='none'
| -- Using src='https://github.com/Maratyszcza/FP16/archive/0a92994d729ff76a58f692d3028ca1b64b145d91.zip'
| -- Downloading FXdiv to /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/FXdiv-source (define FXDIV_SOURCE_DIR to avoid it)
| -- Configuring done
| -- Generating done
| -- Build files have been written to: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/FXdiv-download
| [1/9] Creating directories for 'fxdiv'
| [2/9] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'fxdiv'
| -- Downloading...
|    dst='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/FXdiv-download/fxdiv-prefix/src/b408327ac2a15ec3e43352421954f5b1967701d1.zip'
|    timeout='none'
|    inactivity timeout='none'
| -- Using src='https://github.com/Maratyszcza/FXdiv/archive/b408327ac2a15ec3e43352421954f5b1967701d1.zip'
| ....
| -- [download 100% complete]
| -- verifying file...
|        file='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/FXdiv-download/fxdiv-prefix/src/b408327ac2a15ec3e43352421954f5b1967701d1.zip'
| -- Downloading... done
| -- extracting...
|      src='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/FXdiv-download/fxdiv-prefix/src/b408327ac2a15ec3e43352421954f5b1967701d1.zip'
|      dst='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/FXdiv-source'
| -- extracting... [tar xfz]
| -- extracting... [analysis]
| -- extracting... [rename]
| -- extracting... [clean up]
| -- extracting... done
| [3/9] No update step for 'fxdiv'
| [4/9] No patch step for 'fxdiv'
| [5/9] No configure step for 'fxdiv'
| [6/9] No build step for 'fxdiv'
| [7/9] No install step for 'fxdiv'
| [8/9] No test step for 'fxdiv'
| [9/9] Completed 'fxdiv'
| -- Downloading pthreadpool to /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/pthreadpool-source (define PTHREADPOOL_SOURCE_DIR to avoid it)
| -- Configuring done
| -- Generating done
| -- Build files have been written to: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/pthreadpool-download
| [1/9] Creating directories for 'pthreadpool'
| [2/9] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'pthreadpool'
| -- Downloading...
|    dst='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/pthreadpool-download/pthreadpool-prefix/src/545ebe9f225aec6dca49109516fac02e973a3de2.zip'
|    timeout='none'
|    inactivity timeout='none'
| -- Using src='https://github.com/Maratyszcza/pthreadpool/archive/545ebe9f225aec6dca49109516fac02e973a3de2.zip'
| -- [download 100% complete]
| ....
| -- [download 100% complete]
| -- verifying file...
|        file='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/pthreadpool-download/pthreadpool-prefix/src/545ebe9f225aec6dca49109516fac02e973a3de2.zip'
| -- Downloading... done
| -- extracting...
|      src='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/pthreadpool-download/pthreadpool-prefix/src/545ebe9f225aec6dca49109516fac02e973a3de2.zip'
|      dst='/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/pthreadpool-source'
| -- extracting... [tar xfz]
| -- extracting... [analysis]
| -- extracting... [rename]
| -- extracting... [clean up]
| -- extracting... done
| [3/9] No update step for 'pthreadpool'
| [4/9] No patch step for 'pthreadpool'
| [5/9] No configure step for 'pthreadpool'
| [6/9] No build step for 'pthreadpool'
| [7/9] No install step for 'pthreadpool'
| [8/9] No test step for 'pthreadpool'
| [9/9] Completed 'pthreadpool'
| -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
| -- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
| -- Downloading PSimd to /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/psimd-source (define PSIMD_SOURCE_DIR to avoid it)
| -- Configuring done
| -- Generating done
| -- Build files have been written to: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/build/psimd-download
| [1/9] Creating directories for 'psimd'
| [2/9] Performing download step (git clone) for 'psimd'
| Cloning into 'psimd-source'...
| Already on 'master'
| Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
| [3/9] Performing update step for 'psimd'
| [4/9] No patch step for 'psimd'
| [5/9] No configure step for 'psimd'
| [6/9] No build step for 'psimd'
| [7/9] No install step for 'psimd'
| [8/9] No test step for 'psimd'
| [9/9] Completed 'psimd'
| -- Found PythonInterp: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3.9 (found version "3.9.5")
| -- Python Interpreter: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3.9
| -- Python Include is: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include/python3.9)
| -- pybind11 Include is: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pybind11/include)
| -- numpy Include is: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include)
| Protobuf library: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.20.0.2
| -- Configuring done
| CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: ruy
| -- Generating done
| CMake Warning:
|   Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:
| 
|     LIB_SUFFIX
|     Python3_EXECUTABLE
|     Python_EXECUTABLE
| 
| 
| CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
| WARNING: /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.26681:174 exit 1 from 'cmake -G 'Ninja' -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=ninja $oecmake_sitefile /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/git -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr -DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:PATH=bin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SBINDIR:PATH=sbin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR:PATH=libexec -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR:PATH=/etc -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SHAREDSTATEDIR:PATH=../com -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALSTATEDIR:PATH=/var -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:PATH=lib -DCMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR:PATH=include -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR:PATH=share -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3 -DPython_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3 -DPython3_EXECUTABLE:PATH=/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/python3-native/python3 -DLIB_SUFFIX= -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE=0 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_NO_SYSTEM_FROM_IMPORTED=1 -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_SYSROOT=/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/recipe-sysroot -DTFLITE_BUILD_EVALTOOLS=on -DTFLITE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=on -DTFLITE_ENABLE_NNAPI=on -DTFLITE_ENABLE_NNAPI_VERBOSE_VALIDATION=on -DTFLITE_ENABLE_RUY=on -DTFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK=on -DTFLITE_PYTHON_WRAPPER_BUILD_CMAKE2=on -DTFLITE_ENABLE_EXTERNAL_DELEGATE=on /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/git/tensorflow/lite/ -Wno-dev'
| WARNING: Backtrace (BB generated script):
|       #1: cmake_do_configure, /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.26681, line 174
|       #2: do_configure, /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.26681, line 153
|       #3: main, /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.26681, line 209
| ERROR: Execution of '/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/build-ucm-imx8m-plus/tmp/work/cortexa53-crypto-poky-linux/tensorflow-lite/2.6.0-r0/temp/run.do_configure.26681' failed with exit code 1
ERROR: Task (/workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/meta-imx/meta-ml/recipes-libraries/tensorflow-lite/tensorflow-lite_2.6.0.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 11437 tasks of which 11436 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /workspace-vol/test_workspace/compulab-bsp/sources/meta-imx/meta-ml/recipes-libraries/tensorflow-lite/tensorflow-lite_2.6.0.bb:do_configure
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Happy to receive any help to finish this building process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

1. Uninstalled Docker
2. Deleted every .vhdx file
3. Installed Docker
4. Created a new "empty" .vhdx file (~700MB after starting Docker and VSCode)
5. Relocated it to a new harddrive (The one with 500GB+ left capacity)
6. Resized it with diskpart
7. Confirmed the resizing with an Ubuntu-Terminal, as I needed to use resize2fs
8. Used the same Dockerfile and built just Tensorflow-lite
9. Built the whole package afterwards

Not sure what the problem was, seems to must have been some leftover files, that persisted over several build-data deletions.